# CakePHP 2.0 Basic Authentication always gives 302 redirect instead of 401 unauthorized

Tags: php, cakephp, basic-authentication

I have basic authentication set up in a simple CakePHP 2.0 application. I first set up the application to use regular form authentication, then I added the following line to the `beforeFilter()` of my AppController.php to enable basic http authentication:

`$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic');`

Here's the full AppController:

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
            "Session",
            "Auth" => array(
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'index'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'index'),
                'authError' => "You are not authorized to view this page.",
                'authorize' => array('Controller'),
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
        $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
        $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->user());
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic');
    }
}
?>
```

Ideally I'd like one specific controller (a controller which will expose an API for use with a mobile device) out of the entire application to use only Basic HTTP authentication, and the rest of the controllers to behave like a normal web application.

Currently if I pass incorrect credentials to the controller I get an HTTP 302 response, when I'd really like a HTTP 401 to be passed back. How can I do this?

*edited for typo

Comment: Off-topic: are you sure you want to use Basic for a mobile app?  Basic sends credentials unencrypted which are easily sniffed by local proxies, even with SSL. http://thinkvitamin.com/asides/detect-what-a-mobile-app-is-sending-to-its-servers/

Comment: I agree, it's not ideal. I want to start using Digest Auth, is that a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->user());
    if($this->name == 'Specific') {
            // for the specific controller
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic');
    } else {
            // everything else
    }
}
```

checkout KVZ's rest plugin it may be of interest
https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-rest-plugin

Comment: This is an interesting plugin, but unfortunately your solution doesn't create the functionality I am looking for. I'm unable to get pure HTTP authentication to override the default form-based authentication. Currently it seems if I try to use HTTP Basic auth (and don't provide correct credentials), I get a 302 redirect instead of the expected 401 or 403

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried 2.0 yet, but usually what Auth does is use setFlash to set the error message, then redirect you somewhere to show you that message. That's probably why you're getting the 302 redirect.

How about manually setting the header and then exiting?

e.g.

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **cakePHP 2.x** you can [create a custom status code](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#creating-custom-status-codes) e.g.

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
  return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
} else {
  throw new MissingWidgetHelperException('You are not authorized to view this page.', 401);
}
```